# Notepad++ inserts text on enter

Tags: lua, settings, notepad++

I may have accidentally turned on a weird setting within Notepad++. When I press enter after certain lines, it autofills strange text. [Take a look.](http://www.gfycat.com/SnoopyAggressiveDiplodocus)

Has anyone ever seen anything like this? Restarting notepad doesn't fix it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by the plugin NppCalc, when ActiveCalc is on.

You may have accidentally turned it on with Ctrl-Shift-C if that is still assigned to ActiveCalc.

Turning ActiveCalc off (either with **Ctrl-Shift-C** again or by unchecking **Plugins -> NppCalc -> Active Calc**) should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reset the configuration, or take a look at it manually.

It should be under:

```
%APPDATA%\Notepad++
```

You could copy the folder so you have a backup, then move files one by one until you find out which file has the offending setting in it, then narrow it down from there.

Comment: The problem seems to have fixed itself overnight. Thank you for the help though.